# Aggregating column names that are True in a list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am working with a pandas dataframe that is represented as a large truth matrix.

```
       a1     b2      c3     d4     e5     f6
a1    True   True    False  True   False  True
b2    True   True    False  True   True   True
c3    False  False   True   True   True   False
d4    True   True    True   True   False  True
e5    False  True    True   False  True   False
f6    True   True    False  True   False  True
```

I can grab the counts of rows and their respective `True` counts with:

```
df[df == True].count(axis=0)
```

Which would return:

```
a1: 4
b2: 5
c3: 3
d4: 5
e5: 3
f6: 4
```

Likewise, I can obtain the index with the most True values and it's name with:

```
max_count = max(df[df == True].count(axis=0)
id = df[df == True].count(axis=0).idxmax(axis=0)
```

Which returns `max_count=5` and `id=b2`
I am curious then how I can query that row to return all indices with True in a list.

The ideal output would be:

```
ids = [a1, b2, d4, e5, f6]
```

I have tried this:

```
ids = df[id == True].index.tolist()
```

Which results in a key error and many variations of the above.

Comment: have you tried  ids = df[id == True].index.values.tolist() ?

Comment: I had not tried that. It however also results in a: raise KeyError(key) from err KeyError: False message.

Comment: Wait... what are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: Return the column names that are true for ```b2``` in a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, because you have a boolean matrix here, you can use `sum` with axis=1 to get counts of True values for each row index.

```
df.sum(axis=1)
```

Output:

```
a1    4
b2    5
c3    3
d4    5
e5    3
f6    4
dtype: int64
```

Now, let's find "all" the indexes that have the most True values, using `np.where`:

```
max_true_index = df.index[np.where(df.sum(axis=1) == df.sum(axis=1).max())]
```

max_true_index returns:

```
Index(['b2', 'd4'], dtype='object')
```

Finally, let's return all indexes that have True in these two values or from this list:

```
df.index[df[max_true_index].all(axis=1)]
```

Output:

```
Index(['a1', 'b2', 'd4', 'f6'], dtype='object')
```